# Sum values of array with same key and values

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to sum a value of an array with the same employee no.

Here's the example of the array I'm trying to sum.

```
0 => array:10 [▼
    "employee_no" => "04052018"
    "employee_id" => 317
    "company_id" => 4
    "name" => ""
    "monthly_salary" => 14000.0
    "daily_salary" => 537.0
    "work_hours" => 8
    "sss_deduction" => 0
    "pagibig_deduction" => 100
    "philhealth_deduction" => 192
```

and

```
0 => array:10 [▼
"employee_no" => "04052018"
"employee_id" => 317
"company_id" => 4
"name" => ""
"monthly_salary" => 14000.0
"daily_salary" => 537.0
"work_hours" => 8
"sss_deduction" => 0
"pagibig_deduction" => 100
"philhealth_deduction" => 192
```

they are duplicates array in which i want to get the sum of work hours only to have this result

```
0 => array:10 [▼
"employee_no" => "04052018"
"employee_id" => 317
"company_id" => 4
"name" => ""
"monthly_salary" => 14000.0
"daily_salary" => 537.0
"work_hours" => 16
"sss_deduction" => 0
"pagibig_deduction" => 100
"philhealth_deduction" => 192
```

There are about 24 and more occurrences if this array in my result set in which i want to merge as one summing up the total work hours

Tried this one but getting no luck

```
foreach ($employee_attendance as $row){

    if($row['employee_id'] === $row['employee_id']){
        $payroll_data['work_hours'] += $row['total_hours'];
    }
    $payroll[] = $payroll_data;
}
```

Comment: Did you make any effort to code some of this yourself

Comment: of course I already did.

Comment: Well its always a good idea to show us where you currently are with your code. it helps us understand the question better, and lets us know you are not just asking us to do the work for you

Comment: I updated the question with the one i tried to do

Comment: `if($row['employee_id'] === $row['employee_id']){` wont that ALWAYS be true??

Comment: Yea i figured it out that it also returns true always. I tried using array_sum also but instead sum up everything on the array result

Comment: @kiogipaya Is this laravel?

Comment: Yes it's Laravel @vivek_23

Comment: Is `$employee_attendance` all about ONE person, or is this a list of all employees? Also is there only one employee with this issue or do ALL employees have this issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly. This is a list of all employees. And all of them has an issue, basically i want to merge and sum the duplicate arrays. But i only want the work hours to be summed up.

Comment: Can you not do that all in the model layer in SQL

Comment: You dont actually need to sum an employee with other. You just need to count the amount of times an employee is repited and then multiply one employee is work hours by that. Is you think this comment is at all usefull i can elaborate in an anwer

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to get it sorted out from Eloquent queries itself. However, if you wish, you can also use Collections' methods such as [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby) and [each](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-each) to filter the values based on employee ID and do a [sum](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sum) on them. Finally, have a result variable to store all the results.

**Snippet:**

```
$result = [];

$arr = $arr->groupBy('employee_no')->each(function($item,$key) use (&$result){
                $sum = $item->sum('work_hours');
                $emp_data = $item->first();
                $emp_data['work_hours'] = $sum;
                $result[] = $emp_data;
        });
```

**Full Code:**

```
<?php

$arr = collect([
        [
            "employee_no" => "04052018",
            "employee_id" => 317,
            "company_id" => 4,
            "name" => "",
            "monthly_salary" => 14000.0,
            "daily_salary" => 537.0,
            "work_hours" => 8,
            "sss_deduction" => 0,
            "pagibig_deduction" => 100,
            "philhealth_deduction" => 192
        ],
        [
            "employee_no" => "04052018",
            "employee_id" => 317,
            "company_id" => 4,
            "name" => "",
            "monthly_salary" => 14000.0,
            "daily_salary" => 537.0,
            "work_hours" => 8,
            "sss_deduction" => 0,
            "pagibig_deduction" => 100,
            "philhealth_deduction" => 192
        ],
        [
            "employee_no" => "04052019",
            "employee_id" => 317,
            "company_id" => 4,
            "name" => "",
            "monthly_salary" => 14000.0,
            "daily_salary" => 537.0,
            "work_hours" => 80,
            "sss_deduction" => 0,
            "pagibig_deduction" => 100,
            "philhealth_deduction" => 192
        ]
    ]);

    $result = [];

    $arr = $arr->groupBy('employee_no')->each(function($item,$key) use (&$result){
                $sum = $item->sum('work_hours');
                $emp_data = $item->first();
                $emp_data['work_hours'] = $sum;
                $result[] = $emp_data;
           });

    print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As what others said, it's better to group and sum those work hours when you retrieve it from the database. 
But in case you still want to do it like what you explained above, it can be done like this although it might not be the best way

```
foreach ($employee_attendance as $row){
    // Check if this is the first occurence of the employee number or not
    if (!isset ($payroll_data[$row['employee_no']]['work_hours']) ) {
        // First occurence will set the total hours to the current loop work hours
        $payroll_data[$row['employee_no']]['work_hours'] = $row['work_hours'];
    } else {
        // Second occurence and so on will sum previous total work hours
        $payroll_data[$row['employee_no']]['work_hours'] += $row['work_hours'];
    }
}
```

And the `$payroll_data` structure will be like this:

```
[
    "04052018" => [
        "work_hours" => 16 // Total work hours of this employee number
    ],
    // Repeat for other employee number
]
```

Hence, it's easier for you to check the employee number with their total working hours as well.